# F# CSV FileHelpers

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, csv, f#, filehelpers

Im following the steps described below to read csv but get runtime error at the last line.
(TypeInitializationException)
Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

http://www.markstaples.com/2009/01/08/parsing-csv-files-in-f/

```
module ReadCsv //-------------------------------------  
open System  
open FileHelpers  
[<DelimitedRecord(",")>]  
[<IgnoreFirst(1)>]  
type CsvRecord =  
    class  
       val field1 : string  
    end

type oneRow() =  
    class  
        [<DefaultValue>]  
        val mutable Str1: string  
        [<DefaultValue>]  
       val mutable Str2: string  
   end

let engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof<CsvRecord>)  
let res = engine.ReadFile("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test.csv")  

module main //--------------------------------  
let downcast_Customer_Array = Array.map (fun (a:obj) -> a :?> ReadCsv.CsvRecord)  
let res_Customers = downcast_Customer_Array ReadCsv.res
```

Comment: The path should probably be an `@` string - `@"C:/Users/..."`, otherwise the `/` are interpreted as escape characters.  The error is probably opening a file that doesn't exist

Comment: The escape character is '\', not '/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John's comment is on track, you're probably trying to read a file that doesn't exist. 
In Windows, backslash is used for path separation, not (forward) slash. 
These backslashes need to be escaped in an F# string literal. 
The reason why you're seeing this as `TypeInitializationException` is that this code is executed when the type is loaded. Had it been in a function, it would execute when called instead, and you would get the expected exception.

There are several ways of escaping the backslashes, pick one:

```
let res = engine.ReadFile("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\test.csv")
let res = engine.ReadFile(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.csv")
let res = engine.ReadFile("""C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.csv""")
```

That last one, triple-quoting, is part of F# 3.0. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx

**Edit**
Your real error is obscured by the fact that your code runs in type initialization. Try structuring your code differently:

```
module ReadCsv = //-------------------------------------  
   open System  
   open FileHelpers  

   [<DelimitedRecord(",")>]  
   [<IgnoreFirst(1)>]  
   type CsvRecord =  
       class  
          val field1 : string  
       end

   let read file = 
      let engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof<CsvRecord>)  
      engine.ReadFile(file) 
      |> Array.map (fun row -> row :?> CsvRecord)

module Main = //--------------------------------  
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 
       let results = ReadCsv.read "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test.csv"
       printfn "%A" results
       0 // return an integer exit code
```

Now, instead of `TypeInitializationException` we get a `BadUsageException` with the message "The record class CsvRecord need a constructor with no args (public or private)". Much more useful! Fixing that, the code works as expected:

```
module ReadCsv = //-------------------------------------  
   open System  
   open FileHelpers  

   [<DelimitedRecord(",")>]  
   [<IgnoreFirst(1)>]  
   type CsvRecord() =  
       class  
          [<DefaultValue>]
          val mutable field1 : string  
       end

   let read file = 
      let engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof<CsvRecord>)  
      engine.ReadFile(file) 
      |> Array.map (fun row -> row :?> CsvRecord)

module Main = //--------------------------------  
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 
       let results = ReadCsv.read "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test.csv"
       results |> Seq.iter (fun r -> printfn "%s" r.field1)
       0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Tried  
let res = engine.ReadFile("D:\\test1.csv") and  
let res = engine.ReadFile(@"D:\test1.csv")  
both still give the same exception and the third one
failes to compile.

Comment: That code works perfect. Thanks so much for the help!!
btw, curious how people debug runtime errors in F#. I feel debugging
F# code is a pain due to less availability of information.